# php newline not working

Tags: php

For some reason i cant get the carriage return to appear on the web page.  When i view source code it is fine.
I have tried various iterations of \n  but it is kicking my butt.

```
<?php
    /* Define string */
    $greeting = "Greeting Professor Falken.";
    $question1 = "Would you like to play a Game?";
    print "$greeting \n ";
    print "$question1";

?>
```

Comment: Use `<br/>` to get a line break in HTML. `echo '<br/>'`

Comment: We aren't magicians. Need source code.

Comment: @ryeguy - The code was there just not formatted. @user647484 - You need to indent code 4 spaces for it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 5):

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Nice, I'd never really thought about doing this.

Comment: An added benefit is you don't have to think about escaping!

Answer (score 4):

Use `<br />` instead. HTML renderers strips all white space which includes /n. If you want the newlines to be displayed (for example in text blocks), surround them with `<pre></pre>`

Comment: HTML doesn't strip all whitespace - it just renders all whitespace as a single space (excluding `pre` and `white-space: pre`).

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your code in `<pre>` tags or use `<br />` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
header('Content-type:text/plain');
```

and if for windows `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

There's also the method for the lazy:

```
ob_start("nl2br");   // at the begin of a script
```